# IIS ASP.NET application prewarming for secured controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, startup

I am interested in increasing my site's responsiveness after a deployment. What methods are there for warming up controllers that require authentication for access?

I am aware of the IIS Prewarming functionality, but would that have any effect? I don't believe a request would ever make it to the controller as the forms authentication module would redirect the request to the sign on page.

Are there any other methods outside of IIS Prewarming? Hosting in cloud platforms generally doesn't allow access to it.

Could it be as simple as perhaps have a lazy static field in the global asax that in the value factory it news up all the relevant controllers I wish to warm? (I use view precompliation already)

Comment: I don't understand the issue you're having? What's in the controller that needs warming?

Comment: @KijanaWoodard there's always a lag time for the first time you execute a request against a controller (or per action, i'm not sure), where subsequent hits are dramatically faster. IIS and/or ASP.NET approaches loading your web application very lazily, i want the opposite, to eagerly load everything it possibly needs into memory.

Comment: I've only noticed the whole app needing prewarming. Once the app is warm, I haven't seen anything noticeable on a per controller/action basis. Haven't timed it, but haven't noticed it.